# Is there a way to force structure begins at cacheline?

Tags: c, caching, struct

I have some large structure (> 64bytes), can I assure that each struct begins at a separated cacheline? Or is there some way to enforce that?

Comment: Assuming a cache line size of 64, you can use `_Alignas(64)` (or `alignas(64)` if you `#include <stdalign.h>`) to enforce that the object always starts on a cache line boundary. See [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard provides `_Alignof (constant-expression)` to request extra alignment. For a structure, apply it to the first element:

```
struct MyTag
{
    _Alignas(64) char x[10];
};


#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%zu\n", _Alignof (struct MyTag));  // Prints 64.
}
```

This requires that you have the cache line size as a compile-time constant.

Compilers are not required to support extended alignments but will diagnose if the requested alignment is too large.

If accepted by the compiler, this will provide the requested alignment for objects allocated by the compiler. However, `malloc` might return addresses without the desired alignment. For this, use `struct MyTag *p = aligned_alloc(64, size);`, where `size` is `sizeof *p` for one structure or `N * sizeof *p` for `N` structures.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming gcc, you can use attributes.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html
"you can explicitly specify the alignment (in bytes) that you wish the compiler to use for a given struct or union type. Alternatively, you can leave out the alignment factor and just ask the compiler to align a type to the maximum useful alignment for the target machine you are compiling for."

```
    struct test {
      int  a;
      double b;
      void *n;
      char p[59];
    };
    
    struct test_64 {
      int  a;
      double b;
      void *n;
      char p[59];
    } __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
    
    
    
    int main(void) {
    
      struct test test_var __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
      struct test test_var_simple_align __attribute__ ((aligned));
      
      printf ("sizeof (test):%ld ", sizeof(struct test));
      printf ("__alignof__(test):%ld\n", __alignof__(struct test));
    
      printf ("sizeof (test_64):%ld ", sizeof(struct test_64));
      printf ("__alignof__(test_64):%ld\n", __alignof__(struct test_64));
    
      printf ("sizeof (test_var):%ld ", sizeof(test_var));
      printf ("__alignof__(test_var):%ld\n", __alignof__(test_var));
    
      printf ("sizeof (test_var_simple_align):%ld ", sizeof(test_var_simple_align));
      printf ("__alignof__(test_var_simple_align):%ld\n", __alignof__(test_var_simple_align));
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is no need for compiler extensions. The C standard specifies `_Alignas (64)` to request an alignment of 64 bytes. However, it cannot be applied directly to the structure, but it can be applied to the first member, as `int _Alignas (64) a;`. Compilers are not required to support alignments beyond some fundamental alignment requirement but should emit a diagnostic message if it is beyond what they support. Similarly, you do not need an extension (`__alignof__`) to report the alignment of types; there is a standard way to do it: `_Alignof`. (It does require a type, though, not an object.)

Comment: Use `%zu` to print sizes and alignments, not `%ld`.